# Jquery Mobile .blur() not hiding keyboard

Tags: jquery-mobile, keyboard, blur

I am trying to hide the keyboard when the user searches for something using ' $(#elementID).blur(); '

I had an issue with IOS where in the login page , the keyboard was not hiding.
IOS is now NOT giving me a problem , but Android is.

In Android , the login page hides the keyboard properly , but in the search page , the keyboard still stays there after the search is completed.

Solutions tried:

- I even blurred the element after the search is completed.
- And I tried this and it didnt work too:

  > document.activeElement.blur();

Can anyone give advice?
Thanks!